# Can't get correct results from mysql

Tags: mysql, navicat

I have a table which has an column named `status` whose value can be 1,2 and 3.

Say the table name is ANYTHING, some thread in my app executed a query

```
 SELECT order_num, `status` from ANYTHING WHERE status = 2
```

it will return 2 records as following.

```
order_num             status
D2017101100001            2
D2017101100002            2
```

After that another thread in the same app updated the status of `D2017101100001` to `3` and we can see the status changed to 3 from Navicat client. 
Then triggered the query

```
SELECT order_num, `status` from ANYTHING WHERE status = 2
```

again, but unfortunately we got the same results as before, `D2017101100001` still returned.

And then we executed

```
SELECT order_num, `status` from ANYTHING WHERE status = 3
```

`D2017101100001` will not be returned.

But after a few seconds, everying gets normal `D2017101100001` will be returned from condition `status = 3` and not returned from `status = 2`.

We suspected it's caused by query cache, but when we checked the QChace status the QCache_hits is 0 as below.

```
Variable_name               value
Qcache_free_blocks            1
Qcache_free_memory         1031832
Qcache_hits                   0
Qcache_inserts                0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes          0
Qcache_not_cached          31050313
Qcache_queries_in_cache       0
Qcache_total_blocks           1
Qcache_total_blocks           1
```

We aslo used mybatis but we have diasbled first_level cache for this query and had seen the database hit log, so it seems the root cause still in mysql side.

If anyone encountered this problem before? Please give us some help.

Comment: What is the isolation level for mysql set to?

Comment: READ_COMMITTED. But I don't think it relates to isolation level, because we have seen the change has been commited from Navicat.

Comment: Can we say the table is named ANYTHING other than ORDER

Comment: Yes, it's just a sample. The real name is not ORDER. Just renamed to ANYTHING, thanks for your kindly notice.

Comment: You say you have seen it committed. Have you executed a `commit;` at the end or have you just selected from the table? It is not clear, what you do when in which session. When you see the updated value in another session finally, it could be that your updating session made an implicit commit by issuing another statement. Or that navicat does some weird things (I personally don't trust such clients, native mysql client is the way to go). Oh, and forget about the query cache, it has nothing to do with it, even if it were enabled.

Comment: As I don't have permission to the mysql server, I have  to use some client to connect. And I tested using 2 sessions one navicat and one java session, and verified that I can't query the changes in navicat session before the transaction committed in java. I think this can demenstrate that as I queried the changed value in navicat the updating session must be committed.